# How to override inline css in xamarin forms

Tags: css, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, styling

I developed a xamarin forms appilication. For CSS, I used inline styles which are provided by xamarin forms and the appilication is used by various clients. But now a client want his application to have custom CSS(fonts, colors, etc). How can I override the inline styling for the particular client?

Sample for inline styling which I used:

```
<Label Text="Login to your account" FontFamily="Playfair Display" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

I tried using CSS file and used !important for the necessary fields which didn't work.

Comment: What HTML/CSS does that example render as?  (ie what do you see when using your browser devtools to inspect that element).

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms, you can use Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) to define styling for your application's elements, including customizing fonts, colors, and other properties. If you're using inline styles and want to allow customization for specific clients, you'll need to modify your approach slightly. Here's how you can achieve this:

1. *Create a Global Stylesheet using CSS*:

Create a `.css` file in your Xamarin.Forms project and define the styles you want to apply globally. This file can be named, for example, `globalstyles.css`. In this file, you can define styles using class selectors:

```
.custom-label {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    color: #FF6600;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* Add more custom styles here */
}
```

2. *Link the Global Stylesheet*:

In your Xamarin.Forms application's `App.xaml` file, you can reference the global stylesheet:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <StyleSheet Source="globalstyles.css" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

3. *Assign Class Names to Elements*:

Modify your XAML code to include the class name you defined in the global stylesheet:

```
<Label Text="Login to your account" StyleClass="custom-label" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

4. *Client-Specific Overrides*:
   If you want to allow specific clients to have custom styles, you can conditionally apply style classes in your code-behind. For example, you could have a property that indicates the client's identity and apply the class based on that:

```
// Assume you have a property that identifies the client
bool isClient1 = DetermineIfClient1();

// Apply the appropriate style class
if (isClient1)
{
    customLabel.StyleClass.Add("custom-label-client1");
}
else
{
    customLabel.StyleClass.Add("custom-label");
}
```

In this example, you would create a new style in your CSS file for `custom-label-client1` and define the specific styling for this client.

5. *Use !important Sparingly*:
   While using `!important` can be used to forcefully override styles, it's generally better to structure your CSS and styling in a way that avoids excessive use of `!important`. Instead, use specific selectors and proper class naming to organize your styles effectively.

By following these steps, you can separate your styling concerns into a global stylesheet and customize styles for different clients while maintaining a cleaner and more maintainable codebase.